# trace apache access_log file record called by which html or php file

Tags: apache-2.2, security

I figured out that my access_log have funny records

```
118.101.120.86 - - [20/Apr/2015:23:20:57 +0400] "\xed3.\xbd\xd5\xeb\x16\xca\xa4" 200 378
146.185.239.100 - - [20/Apr/2015:23:31:00 +0400] "GET http://24x7-allrequestsallowed.com/?PHPSESSID=a77ad01b00143PUVJWUGY%40G%5EJFQU HTTP/1.1" 200 378
113.210.128.99 - - [20/Apr/2015:23:32:35 +0400] "\xf1/v#\xd2\xd5\xef\xf7s\x962\xcbZ\x19p\xae\xc9(w2\xa0\x90" 200 378
```

How can I trace, which file they access to able to access the http://24x7-allrequestsallowed.com

I am very new in this area, but I would like to know which malicious file cause them to able to load this.

2. and I also how can I decode those **\xf1/v#\xd2\xd5\xef\xf7s** , any where can decode it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomLog with LogFormat (the %f flag I believe) to configure Apache to log which file was being used to serve a particular request. These requests are most likely bogus though from automated bots up to no good (e.g. trying to see if your web server is vulnerable to an exploit).

See the following links:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog